# CSS with relative URL to background image?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a file structure of:

```
home.html
img/bg_damask1.jpg
css/style.css
```

When I set my body background image I can't get it to load. I've tried:

```
background-image: url('../img/bg_damask1.jpg');
background-image: url('/img/bg_damask1.jpg');
background-image: url('img/bg_damask1.jpg');
```

But none are working. How do I get my css to reference the background image?

ETA: In browser dev tools I see that no matter what file path I put in, the browser is only referencing 'bg_damask1.jpg' without the file path. If I edit it in dev tools the image shows up using option #1. Now I'm stumped as to what's causing the breakdown.

Comment: The first method should work. Check in developer tools of your browser if any other rule overwrite this one.

Comment: also make background-size:cover

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use for this body.

Your css must be like this

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img/bg_damsk1.jpg);
}
```

Also for you example is

```css
body {
 background-image: url(http://www.radioviva.fm.br/images/backgrounds/bg-squares-3d.jpg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

That example you must just change url path to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Third option should be working, check the source code in your webbrowser and check if the image is actually found. If not try reuploading the image, renaming it or placing it in another folder.

Comment: if the OP's CSS is in style.css, the third option won't work.